# How to print a xlsx file inside a web element using Selenium in Python?

Tags: selenium

I'm working on an automatic new post creator bot on Wordpress using Selenium. But I want to know, can I print the content of a xlsx file to the new post field?

The bot will get the path of the xlsx file from user, read it, copy everything inside and paste it. Is it possible?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read an excel and print its content

First run these in a terminal: `pip install openpyxl` and `pip install pandas`

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D:/chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_textarea')

#accept privacy
driver.find_element_by_id('accept-choices').click()

#switch to the iframe where the textarea is
iframe = driver.find_element_by_id('iframeResult')
driver.switch_to_frame(iframe)
#send the excel text in the text area

df = pd.read_excel('D:/given_excel.xlsx',skiprows=1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//textarea[@name='w3review']").send_keys(df.to_string(index=False))
```

where `skiprows=1` will skip the excel header and `index=False` to not see the count of the rows

[image]

Comment: This works. But I wonder, can I print this content to a web element with Selenium?

Comment: ofc you can. I'update the above code. Basically you take the output of the excel and paste it in an input/text area using the send_keys(string)